# javascript singleton with promise

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, singleton, promise

I am wondering if I have a singleton object like this

```
var A = require("js/A");
var singleton = {
    obj : null,

    current: function() {
          if(!this.obj){
             this.fetch();
          }
          return this.obj;
    },
    fetch: function() {
          A.fetch().then(function(result){
             this.obj = result;
          });
    }
}
```

so does it wait for the fetch to come back by the time when we `return this.obj` ?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no.  The fetch is happening asynchronously, so the outer function will return before the callback function passed into `A.fetch()` is executed.

This is the nature of asynchronous programming, and you need to become familiar with promises and/or [jQuery's deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) (which is a *partial* implementation of the [Promises/A](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A) spec)to handle this case.

Here is a nice introduction to [Promises](http://www.promisejs.org/intro/), and [here's another](http://blog.parse.com/2013/01/29/whats-so-great-about-javascript-promises/)

Comment: so it will just return "null" when we call current ?

Comment: either `null` or the value assigned to it after the callback passed into the `fetch` call executes.

Comment: so which means the user will see null and as soon as the fetch returns from the server it will secretly become the new value even though the function already returned ?